# Why does series of a constant diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

It is known that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}3$ diverges, and I suppose it is because the sum of infinitely large amount of terms tends to infinity. But maybe there is some practical proof or theorem about it?

Comment: Well, first of all if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges then $a_n\to 0$. In your series this necessary condition obviously doesn't hold.

Comment: By the way, the singular of "series" is..."series". "Serie" is not a word. Both the singular and plural are "series".

Comment: @user658409 Thank you for informing me, I had a feeling that it sounds wrong. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It diverges because:

1. $(\forall N\in\mathbb N):\sum_{n=1}^N3=3N$;
2. $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty}3N=\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

1-Not every constant series diverges.
Take $ \sum_1^{\infty} 0=0$

2-However if it is a non-zero constant, say, without loss of generality $\epsilon >0$ then $ \sum_1^{\infty} \epsilon \geq \sum_1^{ n \times\lceil{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}\rceil} \epsilon>n$